# How to control turning in Navigation Stack

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a omnidirectional skid steer drive robot. I am implementing Navigation stack for it. Using default planners and default configuration. Whenever I give a close distance goal to the bot it takes huge turns to correct its orientation and misses the target. What should I do to either make it take sharp turns or disable x velocity while on rotation

```
    TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.65
  min_vel_x: 0
  max_vel_theta: 2
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 1

  acc_lim_theta: 5.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5

  holonomic_robot: false
  meter_scoring: true

  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393965/how-to-control-turning-in-navigation-stack/) by [wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/89854/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2022-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try adjusting `min_in_place_vel_theta` default is 0.4 not 1.0, setting at 1 rotates at 1 radian or 57 degrees per second.
This parameter sets the minimum rotational velocity allowed for the base while performing in-place rotations in radians/sec.

More info found here: http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/89854/wolf/) on 2022-01-14**:
Thanks! That made some improvement.